# Opcache + Memcached Together

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, memcached, opcache

my environment

`ubuntu 14.04` , `php 5.5` , `nginx 1.76`

i am using both `opcache` and `xcache` concurrently

```
PHP 5.5.19-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2014 19:33:43) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

can i use both opcache and memchached together .. i dont know whether this allowed or not ?

suggestions invited ? ?

Comment: Yes you can, because they both serve totally different purposes: opcache is a bytecode cache for your php script; memcache is a key/value store for userdata

Comment: can  i also try this combination Nginx + varnish + php +  opcache + memcached + hhvm

Comment: Forget adding hhvm into the mix.... that is effectively a replacement for Nginx+php+opcache, and not sure how well it would play with varnish either..... but you really need to know what you're doing when playing with hhvm, and these questions strongly suggest that you don't know what you're doing yet

Comment: @MarkBaker How is HHVM a replacement for Nginx? A web server is still needed. HHVM is a bytecode compiler, not a webserver with php parser and compiler.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois - HHVM doesn't simply compile PHP code, it embeds it for execution within its own dedicated webserver that is part of the HHVM build

Comment: Though it can always be run behind another webserver like apache or nginx, or can be used in fastcgi mode

Comment: OK, I stand corrected, HHVM >= 3.0 no longer comes with its own built-in webserver, guess I'm a bit out of touch

Comment: memcached + hhvm can be run together ?

Comment: There is no "best" environment..... if there was, then it would be what everybody used simply because it was the "best".... "best" is subjective, dependent on your needs and requirements, skill and knowledge levels, price of hosting, and a whole host of other factors, etc.... and even then, it's subjective

Comment: Even "better performance" is subjective... best use of memory, or of other server resources; fastest execution time for code; fastest database query time (you haven't even identified what database you're using); fastest network latency time? Are you actually caching data with memcached? What would you cache with varnish? Is varnish inside or outside of your webserver? Is memcached running as a cluster of servers, or just a single server, or is it actually on your webserver..... there are no quick, easy, straightforward answers to these questions,.... that's why devops are in such demand

Comment: You have to start asking yourself "what do I want to use memcached for?", "what do I want to use Varnish for?" Don't imply add components to your architecture because you think they're necessary; add them when you know what you need them for

Comment: First of all i will do some R & D on the topics and i will ask then .. Really Thanks @MarkBaker for your vaulble time

Comment: And if you do know what you need a key/value store for, and how to use it; then consider which key/value store is most appropriate for your application.... memcached, redis, couchdb, or others... they all have benefits and drawbacks